# How do I increase the stock when the transaction is cleared at laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel

When I delete transactions I want the stock to increase according to the quantity of drug transactions that have been deleted

datatable controller

```
    public function datatransobat($kode_register){
  $data = Obat_tran::join('obats', 'obat_trans.kd_obat', '=', 'obats.kd_obat')
  ->select(['obat_trans.id', 'obat_trans.kode_rekmed', 'obat_trans.kode_register', 'obat_trans.kd_obat', 'obat_trans.kuantitas', 'obat_trans.subtotal', 'obats.nama_obat'])
    ->where('kode_register', '=', $kode_register);;
    return Datatables::of($data)
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->addColumn('action', function($row){
          $button = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</button>';
          return $button;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->make(true);
}
```

delete function in js

```
    //Proses Hapus
$('#tombol-hapus').click(function () {
    $.ajax({

        url: "../transobat/" + dataId , //eksekusi ajax ke url ini
        type: 'delete',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#tombol-hapus').text('Hapus Data'); //set text untuk tombol hapus
        },
        success: function (data) { //jika sukses
            setTimeout(function () {
                location.reload();
            },1000);
            toastr.error('Data Berhasil Dihapus.');
            $('#konfirmasi-modal').modal('hide'); //sembunyikan konfirmasi modal
            var oTable = $('#data_transobat').dataTable();
            oTable.fnDraw(false); //reset datatable

        }
    })
});
```

destroy controller

```
    public function destroy($id)
{
  $post = Obat_tran::where('id',$id)->delete();


  return response()->json($post);
}
```

Comment: Where do you encounter problems in your code?
Do you not know how to display it again or how to code it in your backend?

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function destroy(Obat_Tran, $post)
{
  $stock_removed = $post->kuantitas;
  $obat = Obat::find($post->obat_id);
  $obat->stock = $obat->stock + $stock_removed;
  $obat->save();
  $post->delete();
  return response()->json($post);
}
```

Comment: And then ofcource put that in an observer, cause so may lines is just nasty ;-)